# sparklyr :: Error reading parquet file using sparklyr library in R

Tags: r, apache-spark, parquet, azure-databricks

I am trying to read `parquet` file from databricks `Filestore`

```
library(sparklyr)
```

###### parquet_dir has been pre-defined

```
parquet_dir = /dbfs/FileStore/test/flc_next.parquet'
```

###### List the files in the parquet dir

```
filenames <- dir(parquet_dir, full.names = TRUE)
"/dbfs/FileStore/test/flc_next.parquet/_committed_6244562942368589642"                                                                   
[2] "/dbfs/FileStore/test/flc_next.parquet/_started_6244562942368589642"                                                                     
[3] "/dbfs/FileStore/test/flc_next.parquet/_SUCCESS"                                                                                         
[4] "/dbfs/FileStore/test/flc_next.parquet/part-00000-tid-6244562942368589642-0edceedf-7157-4cce-a084-0f2a4a6769e6-925-1-c000.snappy.parquet"
```

###### Show the filenames and their sizes

```
data_frame(
  filename = basename(filenames),
  size_bytes = file.size(filenames)
)
rning: `data_frame()` was deprecated in tibble 1.1.0.
Please use `tibble()` instead.
This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
Call `lifecycle::last_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  filename                                                            size_bytes
  <chr>                                                                    <dbl>
1 _committed_6244562942368589642                                             124
2 _started_6244562942368589642                                                 0
3 _SUCCESS                                                                     0
4 part-00000-tid-6244562942368589642-0edceedf-7157-4cce-a084-0f2a4a6…     248643
```

##### Import the data into Spark

```
timbre_tbl <- spark_read_parquet("flc_next.parquet", parquet_dir)
```

##### Error : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

```
Some(<code style = 'font-size:10p'> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors </code>)
```

I would appreciate any help/suggestion

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

The first argument of  `spark_read_parquet` expects a spark connection, check this: `sparklyr::spark_connect`. If you are running the codes in Databricks then this should work:

```
sc <- spark_connect(method = "databricks")
timbre_tbl <- spark_read_parquet(sc, "flc_next.parquet", parquet_dir)
```

Comment: Well that is nowhere mentioned in the question, neither the answer is related to the error you mentioned :). In general as a thumbrule, `dbfs:/` should be used whenever you are using any spark related functions (distributed data), and `/dbfs/` should be used whenever you are working with usual R related functions as they work with the driver node only (not on distributed data). Please research a bit more on this here - https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html.